# Mongodb query distinct sort by numerical order

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to sort the mongodb collection distinct output in numerical order. but I am getting the error message.

This query works, but its not sorting by numeric value.

```
db.cars.distinct( "carId").sort()
```

Trying this query, its giving the error message:

```
db.cars.distinct( "carId").sort().collation({
    locale: "en_US",
    numericOrdering: true
})
```

Error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).collation is not a function at user_script:34:64 at async ShellEvaluator.innerEval (all-standalone.js:6436:1758) at async ShellEvaluator.customEval (all-standalone.js:6436:1902)
```

How to sort this in numeric order?

Thanks

Comment: The distinct method returns an array of distinct values. Depending upon the client program, tool or a driver you need to use the appropriate sort method.

Comment: if you want to use mongoDB to sort, you can use `$group` with `$sort`

Comment: @nimrodserok can you please post the sample query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use mongoDB to sort, one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$carId"}},
  {$sort: {_id: 1}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, res: {$push: "$_id"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GDluoW-wRXe)